# Moving multiple files to a single location in my PC using java command line arguments

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write a program where i am using multiple threads to copy multiples files to a single location in my PC.

My input would be the path of the file(in my PC
0 as a command line argument.
i have to copy multiple files simultaneously to a specific folder in my PC.

File source is command line input
file destination should be a New Folder in my pc.
need to know how to give destination path as directory, and also input as command line argument
This is the method i am calling

```
private static void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
        FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
        FileChannel destChannel = null;
        try {
            sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
            destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
           }finally{
               sourceChannel.close();
               destChannel.close();
           }
```

Comment: You could add each `File` to a `ExecutorService` and allow it to "pop off" the next job when threads become available...oh and your question would be?

Comment: You might also like to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to use command line just check the args[] array in the main method

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
    if( args.length >= 2 ){
       File source = new File(args[0]);
       File dest = new File( args[1] );

       // Check files
       if( source.exists() && source.isDirectory() ){
          // continue check here
       }else{
         // args[0] is not a directory or does not exists
       }
    }
}
```

if you need to iterate over files just use.

```
File[] files = source.listFiles();
for( File file : files ){
   if( file.isDirectory() ){
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: my source is a path , so args[0] only takes the first String so how do i do it , and the destination should be a empty folder in my PC

Comment: Let's say you exec you program like java -jar myprogram c:/path1 c:/empty then you can look at the code above

Comment: If you only have one command argument you must specify in your program what the empty folder should be. This can be done in a .properties file that you specify outside your program and use Spring, Guice or just a plain property loader to load the settings.

Comment: i will use 4 command prompt windows , and upload 4 files to same folder on  another drive which i want the file name to remain same after moving ,

Comment: i have used four threads and the method call to copy the file